# Getting Error while trying to run soap xml using java

Tags: java, automation, soapui

I am using maven-soapui-plugin 4.5.1 and I want to run a particular test step. I am using below code:

```
WsdlProject abc = new WsdlProject(projectXMLPath);
WsdlTestSuite wsdlTestSuite = abc.getTestSuiteByName(testSuiteName);
WsdlTestCase wsdlTestCase = wsdlTestSuite.getTestCaseByName(testCaseName);
WsdlTestCaseRunner wsdlTestCaseRunner = new WsdlTestCaseRunner(wsdlTestCase,new StringToObjectMap());
WsdlTestStep wsdlTestStep = wsdlTestCase.getTestStepByName(testStepName);
wsdlTestCaseRunner.run(wsdlTestStep);
```

Few things -
1. The project xml has 2 test suites, first test suite has the steps and second test suite has the library functions. In SoapUI they are coded as below:

First Test Step Script (Given a request with a valid address is made) from first Test Suite is as below:

```
def proj= null
def workspace = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getWorkspace();

proj= workspace.getProjectByName("Calling")

def testCase = proj.testSuites["Library"].testCases["Successful Calling Steps" ]
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "addressLine1", "xxxx" )
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "city", "xxxx" )
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "state", "xx" )

def testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName("Given a request with a valid address is made")

def runner = null
runner = testStep.run(testRunner, context)
```

2. Second Test Script from Library Test suite has the actual REST request, end point for the webservice and webservice authentication.
3. If we execute the first test step in first test suite in SOAPUI, it internally calls the test step in Library replaces the variable values and makes a REST call to get a response. This works fine in SOAPUI, but when we are calling the first test step by run method in JAVA, it is failing with below error.

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jniwrapper/PlatformContext
    at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.isJXBrowserDisabled(SoapUI.java:1060)
    at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.isJXBrowserDisabled(SoapUI.java:1038)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpAuthenticationRequestFilter.filterAbstractHttpRequest(HttpAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:77)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filterRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:31)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:184)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:123)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.submitRequest(WsdlSubmit.java:76)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.RestRequest.submit(RestRequest.java:209)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequestStep.run(RestTestRequestStep.java:898)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:238)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:224)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner$runTestStep.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at MyClass.simpletest1(MyClass.groovy:109)
    at test.main(test.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jniwrapper.PlatformContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 22 more

What may be missed here that I need to add to resolve the issue? Please help.

Comment: Are you using Maven? Did you download all the dependencies? 4.5.1 is pretty old, are you sure all the dependencies are still available?

Comment: Yes I am using maven 4.5.1 and Soapui free version. Later plugins are available for SoapUI pro version.

Comment: Maven, **the tool**, https://maven.apache.org/ latest is only up to version 3!

Comment: I am using maven-soapui-plugin 4.5.1, soapui free latest version and maven 3.

Comment: Have you considered using a newer version of SoapUI? Starting with version 4.5.2, SoapUI was acquired by SmartBear, and the groupid was updated accordingly: http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoapUI version 4.5.1 is rather outdated, and the required dependencies may no longer be available.

You should use a newer version. Starting from version 4.5.2, SoapUI was purchased by SmartBear, and the groupid of the jars was updated accordingly, which resulted in a different location in Maven repos: http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/